# Looking for a YA book about a magical nanny that heavily featured lady bugs

Tags: story-identification, magic, young-adult

I remember a YA book that involved a family who's babysitter/nanny was implied to be magical, and as I recall she was heavily associated with lady bugs. But I can't remember what the name of the books were.

I can recall some of the cover art, where said babysitter/nanny is helping one of her kids get ready for what might have been a date or a dance. The babysitter is kneeling down as she's helping the girl with her dress, but it looked as if the girl was either floating in the air or there was electricity going through her. Also, I believe the nanny had red hair which I think stood up. The other kids were looking in from the doorway as this was going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a link to the book I'd been trying to find.

It's called *[Dance Magic](http://books.google.com/books/about/Dance_Magic.html?id=xrdFCFQfjKgC)*, and it's the second book of the *Here Comes Heavenly* series by Todd Strasser.

[image: Book Cover]

> Heavenly Litebody is a punk nanny! Everwhere she goes amazing things happen, like at the school dance and the soccer game. And what's with those ladybugs, anyway? And about how my little brother tries to set a magic trap for her.